# Create Objects in panel and arrange objects the new in first not in end

Tags: c#

I want create manually PictureBox and Label on horizontal Panel, The count of PictureBox and Label on panel Unknown maybe 200 or more or less, I use the below code to do that but i face two troubles **first one:**
I want add the new object created in the first not in the end for example if i created items "A B C D E" want it add on Panel "E D C B A" want always the new come to first. 
Note: Panel width "230" Height "710"
**Second trouble:**
Currently when i use Panel scroll bar to go down than add new objects find happen big free space between the last object created and the new and if i used  scroll again to go down and created new object on panel happen more big free space.

```
            int Right = 50, Top = 0;

            // Create Image + Text
            PictureBox pbox = new PictureBox();
            pbox.Size = new Size(140, 80);
            pbox.Location = new Point(Right, Top);
            pbox.Image = Image.FromFile("");
            Panel1.Controls.Add(pbox);


            // Create label
            Label lblPlateNOBAR = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            lblPlateNOBAR.Text = lblPlateNO.Text;
            lblPlateNOBAR.Location = new Point(Right + 20, Top + 80);
            Panel1.Controls.Add(lblPlateNOBAR);

            Top = Top + 150;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make the objects insert into the panel, you'd need to move the controls which already exist in the panel:

```
int right = 50;

// Create Image + Text
PictureBox pbox = new PictureBox();
pbox.Size = new Size(140, 80);
pbox.Location = new Point(right, 0);
pbox.Image = Image.FromFile("");

// Create label
Label lblPlateNOBAR = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
lblPlateNOBAR.Text = lblPlateNO.Text;
lblPlateNOBAR.Location = new Point(right + 20, 80);

foreach(var control in Panel1.Controls)
{
    control.Top = control.Top + 150;
}

Panel1.Controls.Add(pbox);
Panel1.Controls.Add(lblPlateNOBAR);
```

Comment: foreach (Control control in pnSettings.Controls)
                        {
                            control.Top = control.Top + 150;
                        }

Comment: @user1530499 more concisely : 
`foreach (Control control in pnSettings.Controls) control.Top+=150;`
No need for eyebrow brackets and you can use += operator :)

Answer (score 0):

I know it might seem that I'm not answering your question, but you can take little time to know my suggestion too. I don't know what you wanna achieve, but when you want to make such a sophisticated program, it's a better practice that you do all the work needed yourself, not relying on Windows Forms Controls. Trying to add, remove, change location of lots of controls will reduce the application performance very much. I suggest that you draw, for example your pictures, yourself, using `Graphics` and `Image` objects and `Paint` event. Also handle things like clicking and selecting pictures by `MouseEvents`. It might seem a little hard at first, but after you've done this you have **far better performance and flexibility**. This becomes more important considering you mentioned you wanna place 200 pictures in the panel. This also prevents trouble of flickering that appears when you change position of many controls.  It's good to mention that to do scrolling in this case, you can place a `Panel` inside of a *Parent* `Panel` and use `AutoScroll` feature only for the parent panel to handle scrolling. This way you don't have to care about the scrolling anymore.

Comment: Great, I like your idea for Parent panel and sub panel it's solved problem easy. Regarding draw objects i don't know how that will make performance better than using Windows Forms Controls, Sorry because i don't have experience in this area could you please advise me link to explain that or explain to me more :)

Comment: @user1530499 I guess you will see some flickering when you add many controls and shift all of them 150 px. Also if you add 200 controls at one time it will take some time. Also storing 200 controls take much memory. Each control class stores many information that you don't really need. Nowadays PCs have much greater resources than before, but this does not mean we should spoil resources. There should be an appropriate correspondence with the job and resources it takes. However, sometimes its better to do what you know already right now, but consider better ways for the future.